# how to integrate virtual keyboard in java

Tags: java, user-interface, keyboard

I want to use virtual keyboard in my **java SE**  application to input some details in various Text Fields. In the same time, I want to integrate the used keyboard in the application. So I want to ask two question:

1. Is there any way to integrate any virtual keyboard in **java SE** application ?
2. If yes, how can I do this integration ?

This is all on windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by virtual keyboard? Windows has an on-screen keyboard which you can type with. Do you want to duplicate that functionality in your Java GUI application?

Comment: virtual keyboard or on screen keyboard. it's the same -not hardware-. i want to use any virtual keyboard -on screen for windows or else-  to be integrated in my GUI to make them in one window.

Comment: Did my answer work? Feel free to ask me any questions if it didn't. If it did, make sure to mark it best answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making multiple buttons for each key. Have an action listener object, and add the instance to every button.

```
actionlistenerclass actionlistenerobj = new actionlistenerclass();
Jbutton z = new JButton ("z")
z.addActionListener(actionlistenerobj)
```

(obviously you would want to add **actionlistenerclass**)

Next, have the letter that corresponds to the button get printed each time the button is hit. To do this, there are many approaches. For example, inside the textbox declaration append the string the user enters:

```
JTextField letters = new JTextField(

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("lettervariable")


);
```

Something like that would take every letter the user enters using on screen gui, and add it into textfield letters.

```
~ { Rich }
```